# MySQL PDO Prepared Statement with VARBINARY

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, password-hash

I have a MySQL database with a username and password. Username is varchar(25) and password is VARBINARY(250). Passwords are generated into hashes through PHP's password_hash function and are then binded with PDO in order to be stored into the VARBINARY(250) field. The problem arises when the field is populated as VARCHAR instead of VARBINARY.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO logins (username, password) VALUES (:USERNAME, cast(:PWD as binary(250)));
$stmt->bindValue("USERNAME", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue("PWD", password_hash($password, $algorithm, ['cost' => 5]), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

**Password results to being stored as:** $2y$05$bwnq0NT4WLZorHQ/mV7CjeD7jY7fScK46BqKesVXw5o0WyXg1Ea0K

However, if I run this...

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO logins (username, password) VALUES (:USERNAME, cast('$2y$05$bwnq0NT4WLZorHQ/mV7CjeD7jY7fScK46BqKesVXw5o0WyXg1Ea0K' as binary(250)));
$stmt->bindValue("USERNAME", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

**The password results to being stored as intended:**
2432792430352f6d5637436a6544376a59376653634b343642714b6573565877356f3057795867314561304b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

In conclusion, my guess would be that PHP's password_hash function delays/interferes with casting the generated hash into binary. I'm not sure how to resolve this. Any ideas?

Comment: It is recommended to use a database field of type `varchar(255)`, is there a reason you declare it as `varbinary(250)`? Furthermore your cost factor is very low, it should be about 10, i assume this is for debugging reasons?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.